# Automatic redirection on 302 status

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-2.7, redirect

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/someurl",
            data: $("#send_application_number").serialize(), 
            success: function(response, textStatus, request) {
                #responseType = request.getResponseHeader('Location')
                $("#captchapopup").foundation("reveal","open")
                $("#viewstate").val(response['viewstate'])
                $("#eventvalidate").val(response['eventvalidate'])
                $("#appl_num").val(response['appl_num'])
                #loc = getcaptchaimage(response['viewstate'], response['eventvalidate'])
                loc = '/anotherurl?viewstate=' + response['viewstate'] + '&eventvalidate=' + response['eventvalidate']
                $("#captchaimage").attr('src', loc)
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Could not get response to session login request");
            }
        });
```

As you can see this is a script for running a modal pop-up to display a captcha. BUT, I may redirect to another url as well, instead of displaying the modal, which is why I sent a 302 redirect (and a url of course) from back-end assuming it would redirect automatically. It did , BUT the rest of the script also executed as well, which brought it back to the modal.

How do I achieve an if-else kind of redirect? That if 'Location' is present, redirect and don't execute the rest of the script?

Comment: AJAX is a request in the _background_, and that means you can not redirect the “foreground” from there via HTTP. Use `location.href="…"` to redirect from within your success handler. (Have your server send it a value that it can base that decision on.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX is a request in the *background*, and that means you can not redirect the “foreground” (browser UI) from there via HTTP.

Use `location.href="…"` to redirect from within your success handler. (Have your server send it a value that it can base that decision on.)